# how to access application URL from host machine?

Tags: tomcat, localhost, virtualbox

I am running my web application (.war) on tomcat in a Linux system running on my virtual-box. My application is running on localhost:8080 on the Linux virtual machine. Is there a way to access the application URL from my host(my machine which hosts the virtualbox. windows 7) ?

Answer (score 1):

your host machine and vm machine must be connected to each other. at first you should be sure that they are successfully connected. then each machine have one ip address in that network so you can use the vm-machine ip and also tomcat port to connect from host pc.
(by defaults connection between hosts and vm machines goes on 192.168.1.X scope and you can see it on you VM network adapter)